# Double inverted commas from mysql command causing trouble in java string

Tags: java, mysql

I am using the following command to fetch report from my MySQL database. It works fine in the MySQL console but when i try using it in my Java code as a string, it starts throwing errors.

```
mysql -u root -ppass -e "SELECT * from CEM_LEGACY_INV" DBNAME | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/' > /home/shahed/Desktop/filename.csv
```

Instead of the query mentioned here, I want to use a string variable which has the query defined in it.

Comment: Show us the Java code you are trying to get to work.

Comment: String query = prop.getProperty("querydownload");
   System.out.println(query);
     String command = "mysql -u root -ptest -e ""+query+""  CMS_SCS_PORTAL | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/' > /home/shahed/Desktop/filename.csv";

Comment: You will of course need to escape all double quotes inside the String, otherwise Java will throw compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escap double quotes(") and back slash(\) - In java, You can escap this character using back slash(\).

You can try something like below -

```
String command = "mysql -u root -ppass -e \"SELECT * from CEM_LEGACY_INV\" DBNAME | sed 's/\\t/\",\"/g;s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/' ";
```